# Problema para levantar o servidor Apache com XAMPP no Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, xampp

Estou utilizando o XAMPP no Ubuntu 17.04 e estou enfrentando um probleminha muito chato para levantar o servidor apache.

Ao entrar no diretório `/opt/lampp` e executar o comando `./lampp start` é retornado o seguinte problema abaixo:

[image: Erro no XAMPP]

Depois de pesquisar bastante sobre o problema eu vi um tópico que sugeria fazer os seguintes passos abaixo:

```
/etc/init.d
./apache2 stop
```

Esta dica de fato resolve, porém sempre que o computar reinicia é necessário fazer exatamente a mesma coisa para levantar o servidor apache pelo XAMPP.

Eu gostaria de resolver isto definitivamente.

Comment: O StackOverflow não é bem para esse propósito, veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, enfim...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update-rc.d -f apache2 remove
```

ou

```
systemctl disable apache2
```

Usando o usuário root.

Comment: Tentei os dois comandos, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Poderia postar o erro @MatheusNascimento ?

Comment: Amigo, aparentemente  o problema com o servidor apache foi resolvido. Porém sempre que dou um `./lampp start` recebo a informação de que o servidor Apache e o MySQL estão OK, mas ao clicar no link do phpMyAdmin recebo a seguinte mensagem abaixo:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6nSv0JDMQPQRV9hVkZJcWNwb0E

Para resolver preciso fazer o mesmo que eu fazia antes com o apache:
`/etc/init.d
./mysql stop`

Sabes me dizer como resolver também?

Comment: Mesma coisa, com o mysql... `systemctl disable mysqld` ou algo assim...